# Use Typescript declaration types inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

After installing types for a library such as "@types/openlayers" how can I then use these for inline type definitions for things like React props:

```
import Map from "ol/Map";    
import { Map as MapTypes } from "@types/openlayers"; // Error: Cannot import type declaration files.

export type Props = {
    mapInstance: MapTypes;
}

export const OlMap: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props): JSX.Element => {
   const currentMap = props.mapInstance;
   ...
}
```

Comment: [openlayers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers) seems to be deprecated.  Did you mean to use (or are you actually using) "ol"?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers which is the import above is not deprecated.

Comment: Which package are you actual applying types to though?  openlayers or ol?  Typically, the `@types/*` matches the package name exactly.  Which is why I think you would want https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol instead.

Comment: I have added the actual package above as an import, its 'ol'

Comment: Ah, that may be the issue then.  Can you try with the `@types/ol` package instead and pull the type out of `ol`?  It may still be exported somewhere else, but I think the types and actual package need to match first.

Comment: You need to install types from `@types/ol` then

Comment: Ok thanks I will give that a go, if you could expand this into an answer it would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it from the actual package that is being typed, not the `@types/*` module.  For example, with `react-router`, you add `@types/react-router` but to pull out the `RouteProps` interface, you use `import {RouteProps} from "react-router";`.

---

Additionally, from your edits, it seems that you *may* be using the wrong `@types/*` package.  You mention using [`@types/openlayers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers) but then mention that you are using the package [`ol`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol), which should probably use the [`@types/ol`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol) package for types.

Note [declaration file consumption](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html):

> For the most part, type declaration packages should always have the
> same name as the package name on `npm`, but prefixed with `@types/`

After running `yarn add ol @types/ol` (or `npm i ol @types/ol`)

This seems to be using the right types:

```
import MapTypes from "ol/Map"; // Note that I don't need "{}" or "as" here
// import {Map as MapTypes} from "ol"; or pull it out of the root export

export type Props = {
    mapInstance: MapTypes;
}

export const OlMap: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props): JSX.Element => {
   const currentMap = props.mapInstance;
   ...
}
```

Comment: But in many cases the definitions type exports have the same name as the package export. For example with OpenLayers and @types/openlayers the types for the OpenLayers module "Map" are also exported as "Map" from @types/openlayers. How can this be distinguished?